# Django give a field default value = pk

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to give a field in Django a default value = value of pk, is this possible ?

I've found an old question about giving a field default = value of another field but it doesn't really help when working with pk value :
[How do I set default field value to value of other field in a Django model?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3475504/how-do-i-set-default-field-value-to-value-of-other-field-in-a-django-model/47140493)

Basicly is something like this possible using pk instead of "name" variable ? :

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
fullname = models.CharField(max_length=100,default=name)

def clean(self):
  self.fullname=name
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Django creates auto primary keys, the model will have a field called "id" and it is also called "pk"

If you access your database you'll be able to see it.

[image: SQL Database screentshot]

If you want to set your own primary key you will need to do something like:

```
custompk = models.someField(primary_key=True)
```

As your question is vague I've attempted to answer to the best of my ability.

If you are trying to access a PK/ID of an object in a view let me know and I can help with that as well. :)