# Django UserProfile Model get User.first_name as the default value of UserProfile.display field

Tags: django, django-models

I am extending the `User` table to add new fields. In `UserProfile` I have a column `display`.

I want to set default of `display' column to full name from` User` table

How can I access foreign key fields inside the `UserProfile`?

```py
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    
    user = models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    
    def get_upload_avatar_to(self, filename):
        return f"images/avatar/{self.user.id}/{filename}"

    def display_name(self):
        if self.display:
            return self.display
        return self.get_full_name()


    def get_full_name(self):
        return self.user.first_name + " " +  self.user.last_name

   
    bio    = models.TextField(default="", blank=True)
    display    = models.CharField(default=get_full_name,max_length=512,blank=True)
```

`display = models.TextField(default=get_full_name, blank=True)`

Is it possible to assign default value to Foreign table(User.first_name and User.last_name) ?

Above code gives error
`get_full_name() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'`

My question is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3475504/how-do-i-set-default-field-value-to-value-of-other-field-in-a-django-model)

How do I add to unicode function `display_name`?

Answer (score 0):

First, be aware that `User` is based on `AbstractUser` that contains `first_name` and `last_name` fields as well as a `property` called `get_full_name` which concatenates both fields.

Secondly, I would advise in altering your model name in order to improve code readability:

models.py

```py
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model


class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(get_user_model(), on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def get_upload_avatar_to(self, filename):
        return f"images/avatar/{self.user.id}/{filename}"
    
    avatar = models.ImageField(upload_to=get_upload_avatar_to, null=True, blank=True)
    bio = models.TextField(default="", blank=True)
    display = models.TextField(blank=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.display:
            self.display = self.user.get_full_name()
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

tests.py

```py
class UserTestCase(TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.user = get_user_model().objects.create(
            first_name='Test',
            last_name='User',
            username='test_user',
            password='testpass123'
        )
    
    def test_profile_display(self):
        Profile.objects.create(
            user=self.user
        )
        self.assertEqual(self.user.profile.display, 'Test User')
```

Comment: Hi,I need to show full name as default value  not on save